# Web Role - Implementing In-Role Caching crashes application (Local + Production)

Tags: c#, caching, azure

I am working on a website project (converted to Web Role) to use In-Role Windows Azure Caching. Everything is working flawlessly, but the moment I enable caching, the application crashes with apparent no useful message in either IIS logs or Event Viewer. All I get is -

Event code: 3005 
Event message: An unhandled exception has occurred. 
Event time: 21/09/2013 23:59:39 
Event time (UTC): 21/09/2013 22:59:39 
Event ID: 440c14c6c5f848b683cf33b2a553b42c 
Event sequence: 3 
Event occurrence: 1 
Event detail code: 0

Exception information: 
    Exception type: SocketException 
    Exception message: No such host is known
   at Microsoft.ApplicationServer.Caching.AsyncResultNoResult.EndInvoke()
   at Microsoft.ApplicationServer.Caching.AsyncResult`1.EndInvoke()
   at Microsoft.ApplicationServer.Caching.SocketConnectionFactory.EndConnect(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
   at Microsoft.ApplicationServer.Caching.TcpClientChannelFactory.TcpConnectionCallback(IAsyncResult result)

I already have Windows Azure SDK 2.1 and also Windows Azure Caching 2.1 versions. I tried solution suggested here to no avail -

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/cie/archive/2013/08/08/windows-azure-caching-2-1-0-0-no-such-host-is-known.aspx

I have got 2 instances of web role with following settings in service configuration -

```
<Setting name="Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Plugins.Caching.ClientDiagnosticLevel" value="4" />
<Setting name="Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Plugins.Diagnostics.ConnectionString" value="UseDevelopmentStorage=true" />
<Setting name="Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Plugins.Caching.NamedCaches" value="{&quot;caches&quot;:[{&quot;name&quot;:&quot;default&quot;,&quot;policy&quot;:{&quot;eviction&quot;:{&quot;type&quot;:0},&quot;expiration&quot;:{&quot;defaultTTL&quot;:10,&quot;isExpirable&quot;:true,&quot;type&quot;:1},&quot;serverNotification&quot;:{&quot;isEnabled&quot;:false}},&quot;secondaries&quot;:0}]}" />
<Setting name="Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Plugins.Caching.DiagnosticLevel" value="4" />
<Setting name="Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Plugins.Caching.CacheSizePercentage" value="30" />
<Setting name="Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Plugins.Caching.ConfigStoreConnectionString" value="UseDevelopmentStorage=true" />
```

and following entries in web.config of web role

```
<sessionState mode="Custom" customProvider="defaultProvider" cookieless="UseCookies">
<providers>
<add cacheName="default" name="defaultProvider" dataCacheClientName="default" applicationName="TravelEagle" type="Microsoft.Web.DistributedCache.DistributedCacheSessionStateStoreProvider, Microsoft.Web.DistributedCache" />
</providers>
</sessionState>

<dataCacheClients>
<dataCacheClient name="default">
<autoDiscover isEnabled="true" identifier="TravelEagle" />
</dataCacheClient>    
</dataCacheClients>
<cacheDiagnostics>
<crashDump dumpLevel="Off" dumpStorageQuotaInMB="100" />
</cacheDiagnostics>
```

If I try to run the application with Azure Emulator, I get another error:

A process serving application pool '5e45b35f-ccd3-485e-8f12-b70178ffd1a3' terminated unexpectedly. The process id was '11096'. The process exit code was '0xfffffffe'.

and

{0} failed to refresh lookup table, exception: {Microsoft.Fabric.Common.OperationCompletedException: Operation completed with an exception ---> Microsoft.Fabric.Federation.RoutingException: The target node explicitly aborted the operation
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at Microsoft.Fabric.Common.OperationContext.End()
   at Microsoft.Fabric.Federation.FederationSite.EndRoutedSendReceive(IAsyncResult ar)
   at Microsoft.Fabric.Data.ReliableServiceManager.EndRefreshLookupTable(IAsyncResult ar)}

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I had to supply my storage account connection string instead of usedevelopmentstorage.